# SQLAlchemy metadata column type with Postgresql interval hour to second

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Abbreviations:

- pg = postgresql
- sa = sqlalchemy

Environment:

- pg 9.6.2
- sa 1.1.9

I have a table with a column using a [field restricted interval type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html):

```
interval hour to second(0)
```

I have an engine with string as `'postgresql://....'`. When I execute:

```
meta = sa.MetaData(connection)  
meta.reflect()
```

I get:

```
SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'interval hour to second' of column 'Visit duration'
  (attype, name))
```

and a `Column` with `NullType` instead of `INTERVAL`:

```
Column('Visit duration', NullType(), table=<rep>)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to restrict the column like that? There is no difference between `interval hour to second(0)` and `interval(0)` (only the lower bound holds importance; f.ex. `'1 sec'::interval minute` is parsed as `'0'::interval`, so actually even that kind of restriction has limited use: it won't produce any errors, just will lose information silently).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Postgresql dialect in SQLAlchemy [maps only a subset of the field restricted interval types](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py#L1303):

```
ischema_names = {
    ...
    'interval': INTERVAL,
    'interval year to month': INTERVAL,
    'interval day to second': INTERVAL,
    ...
}
```

Those 2 [were added a long time ago](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/commit/e8854fe945e94d0fe654e83397c47f8b0fb1f1e8#diff-d33159d80d3deef1d5bdcd057dcc3d6b), in 2009 to be exact. Given a table:

```
create table test (
    id serial primary key,
    duration interval hour to second,
    duration2 interval year to month
);
```

SQLAlchemy is happy to map the 2nd duration column to [`INTERVAL`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.INTERVAL) type, but as you've noted the 1st gets [`NullType`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.NullType), because:

> `NullType` is used as a default type for those cases where a type cannot be determined, including:
>
> - During table reflection, when the type of a column is not recognized by the Dialect
> - ...

This on the other hand will not entirely prevent you from using that column:

> The `NullType` can be used within SQL expression invocation without issue, it just has no behavior either at the expression construction level or at the bind-parameter/result processing level. `NullType` will result in a `CompileError` if the compiler is asked to render the type itself, such as if it is used in a `cast()` operation or within a schema creation operation such as that invoked by `MetaData.create_all()` or the `CreateTable` construct.

For example with data:

```
[local]:5432 user@sopython=> insert into test (duration) values ('1 hour'::interval);
INSERT 0 1
[local]:5432 user@sopython*=> insert into test (duration) values ('34 minutes 1 second'::interval);
INSERT 0 1
[local]:5432 user@sopython*=> commit;
```

And in Python:

```
In [2]: metadata.reflect()
/home/user/Work/SO/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py:2517: SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'interval hour to second' of column 'duration'
  (attype, name))

In [3]: engine.execute(metadata.tables['test'].select()).fetchall()
Out[3]: 
[(1, datetime.timedelta(0, 3600), None),
 (2, datetime.timedelta(0, 2041), None)]
```

You cannot recreate the table using the reflected `Table` instance though:

```
In [4]: from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable

In [5]: from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

In [6]: print(CreateTable(metadata.tables['test']).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CompileError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
  ...
CompileError: (in table 'test', column 'duration'): Can't generate DDL for NullType(); did you forget to specify a type on this Column?
```

Comment: Note that this will be fixed when SQLAlchemy 1.2 is released https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3959/support-reflection-of-postgresql-interval